# Elasticsearch not indexing field named “type” in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

With single table inheritance, facing an issue with indexing a specific column named "type" in a table. The table has two cols of interest (among others), "product_name" and "type". The "product_name" field is indexed properly , the "type" field is not getting indexed at all - any ideas on troubleshooting this? Using elasticsearch-ruby gem with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`elasticsearch-model`](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) to index your rails models the type column is excluded by default. Basically, [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) gets called on your model to provide fields for elasticsearch to add to the index.

In order to add fields to the index that aren't returned in `as_json` you'll need to provide an implementation of `as_indexed_json`. The process is described under [Model serialization](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#model-serialization) in the readme.

You'll probably need to do something like:

```
def as_indexed_json(options = {})
  as_json(methods: :type)
end
```

This will add the type to the json that is used to index the object.